# Getting a new laptop, need to replace harddrives.

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I'm getting a Dell Inspiron 7559 with initially nothing but a 256GB SSD which has a Windows 10 pre-installed. It will have a slot left for a hard drive and I plan to put in the one I currently have in my laptop which has Windows 7 installed. 
When I put it in will Windows 7 also work cause I'd rather that not happen since I Just need this one for the space. Is there any way around this?

Comment: It will not work.  The Windows 7 installation will not be able to activate on your new hardware.  Just install the drive then format it.

Comment: Thank you, I had another question that if I formatted the Local Disk with the Windows 7 on it. It will basically function as a normal drive right?

Comment: It is a HDD.  It already functions like a "normal drive"

Comment: Thanx for the answers. Have a good day :D

Answer (score 0):

Using a drive with a OS installed on another motherboard/CPU/computer has little to no chance to run the OS on this computer due to potential driver and compatibility problems and even if you manage to run the Os you would encounter many and frequent BSODs.

If you have a OS on the SSD and the SSD is the first drive on the boot list you can freely use the HDD as a storage drive even if it has a OS and other data on it.

If you'd like to run the applications and games from your old HDD you would need to reinstall them on the new OS since every OS has its own registry and when an application/game is installed it would create an entry in the registry.

When installing a new OS it is highly recommended to have all other storage devices (HDDs, flash drives, etc.) disconnected from the system and only have the drive that you want to install the OS on plugged in the computer as the installer may put parts of the installation on other drives such as the recovery or boot partition.

Once you have connected the old drive and made sure that the SSD is on top of the boot order in the BIOS it is recommended to back all the data up from the boot partition of the old drive (the old C partition) and then delete it along with the old recovery and system partitions in order to avoid future issues.

One tip from me: since you are reusing an old drive I would first check its health with a diagnostic tool from the manufacturer and make sure it is still healthy and safe to store your data.